# JavaScript Dynamic Button onClick event (variable scope)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

### Background

I am dynamically creating quite a few buttons based on a JSON object I get back from an AJAX request that queries a database.

Each button then needs to make subsequent AJAX calls to that same database, depending on information I put into each button's `onClick` function.

Basically, the url is `"api/{foo}/{bar}/{thing}/"`, And if I call just `"api/"` it gives me all possible options for `foo`. And if I call `"api/book/"` it'll give me all possible options for `bar` where `foo = "book"`, and so on....

### The Approach I am trying.

```js
//getJSON is a promise function that returns a JSON object
getJSON("api")
         // volumes is the JSON object that contains an array of objects
         // each object is {book:"someTitle",url:"titleShorthand"}
        .then((volumes) => {
            for (var vol in volumes) {
                //create Button returns a document.crateElement(input) 
                   //with type=button and value = the passed in param.
                var btn = createButton(volumes[vol].book)
                btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    getJSON("api/" + volumes[vol].url)
                    .then((books) => {
                        console.log(books)
                    })
                })
                volumeDiv.appendChild(btn)
            }
        })
```

### The Problem

All the button.onClick events are the same, as in the `console.log(books)` only gives me the last set of books no matter which button I click. `volumes[vol].url` seems to be getting rewritten with every iteration of the for loop, for every button, not just the newly created button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're declaring a function inside of a `for` loop. The value of `volume[vol]` is always going to be the last value by the time that the function you've declared inside the loop is run because of how [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) work.

To get around this you can use a [higher order function](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html).

I had to mock some functions to get this snippet to work but you'll have to write a function like `getEventListener` in your code to get this working.

```js
var volumeDiv = document.getElementById('container')

function getJSON (url) {
  return new Promise (resolve => {
    var vol1 = {
      book: "vol1",
      url: "vol1"
    }
    var vol2 = {
      book: "vol2",
      url: "vol2"
    }
    var map = {
      'api': { vol1, vol2 },
      'api/vol1': vol1,
      'api/vol2': vol2
    }
    resolve(map[url])
  })
}

function createButton (name) {
  console.log(`creating button ${name}`)
  var btn = document.createElement('input')
  btn.type = 'button'
  btn.value = name

  return btn
}

function getEventListener (url) {
  return () => {
    getJSON(url)
    .then((books) => {
      console.log(books)
    })
  }
}

getJSON("api")
  .then(volumes => {
    for (var vol in volumes) {
      var volumeUrl = volumes[vol].url
      var btn = createButton(volumes[vol].book)
      btn.addEventListener('click', getEventListener("api/" + volumeUrl))
      volumeDiv.appendChild(btn)
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="container" />
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'd be very appreciative if you would mark my answer as correct.